# Basic streaming audio works in 2.1 but not in 2.2

Tags: android, audio-streaming, android-2.2-froyo

My simple audio streaming app works perfectly in 1.6 and 2.1 does not work in 2.2. I have no clue as to why. It works fine on the emulator, on actual 2.2 devices the audio stops unexpectedly after about 10 minutes or so.  When I looked at logcat on my phone (HTC EVO) I see this:

```
I/HTTPStream(   65): 1358 Bytes read, progress 34346/65536
I/HTTPStream(   65): 1358 Bytes read, progress 35704/65536
I/HTTPStream(   65): 1359 Bytes read, progress 37063/65536
I/HTTPStream(   65): 1358 Bytes read, progress 38421/65536
I/HTTPStream(   65): 1358 Bytes read, progress 39779/65536
I/HTTPStream(   65): 1359 Bytes read, progress 41138/65536
I/HTTPStream(   65): 2716 Bytes read, progress 43854/65536
I/HTTPStream(   65): 1359 Bytes read, progress 45213/65536
I/HTTPStream(   65): 1358 Bytes read, progress 46571/65536
```

and then all of a sudden:

```
E/HTTPStream(   65): recv failed, errno = 11 (Try again)
I/HTTPDataSource(   65): Retry ... 0 times left
W/HTTPStream(   65): Calling connect()...
I/AudioHardwareQSD(   65): AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby.
D/StreamProcess(   65): OutputStreamProcess::ResetAOLC()
W/HTTPStream(   65): Returned from connect()...
E/HTTPDataSource(   65): retrying connection failed
V/MediaPlayerService(   65): [2] notify (0x355d0, 4, 0, 0)
I/MediaPlayer( 1719): MediaPlayer handleMessage what=4
I/Prefetcher(   65): [0x3db60] cache below low water mark, filling cache.
W/HTTPStream(   65): Calling connect()...
W/HTTPStream(   65): Returned from connect()...
V/MediaPlayerService(   65): [2] notify (0x355d0, 4, 0, 0)
I/MediaPlayer( 1719): MediaPlayer handleMessage what=4
I/Prefetcher(   65): [0x3db60] cache below low water mark, filling cache.
E/HTTPStream(   65): recv failed, errno = 9 (Bad file number)
V/MediaPlayerService(   65): [2] notify (0x355d0, 4, 0, 0)
I/MediaPlayer( 1719): MediaPlayer handleMessage what=4
I/Prefetcher(   65): [0x3db60] cache below low water mark, filling cache.
E/HTTPStream(   65): recv failed, errno = 9 (Bad file number)
V/MediaPlayerService(   65): [2] notify (0x355d0, 4, 0, 0)
I/MediaPlayer( 1719): MediaPlayer handleMessage what=4
I/Prefetcher(   65): [0x3db60] cache below low water mark, filling cache.
```

The code is basically directly from Google's own docs "Playing from a file or stream" here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html.

Again it works perfectly on 1.6 and 2.1 and the 2.2 *emulator*, but fails like above on 2.2 *devices*.

This is driving me crazy, any ideas?  Thanks.

EDIT: Here's another example of the logcat on my phone when it runs, all of a sudden receive fails, and the server is "gone":

```
I/HTTPStream( 65): 29329 Bytes read, progress 29329/65536
I/HTTPStream( 65): 1448 Bytes read, progress 30777/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 1448 Bytes read, progress 32225/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 2896 Bytes read, progress 35121/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 1448 Bytes read, progress 36569/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 2896 Bytes read, progress 39465/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 5792 Bytes read, progress 45257/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 1448 Bytes read, progress 46705/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 4344 Bytes read, progress 51049/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 7240 Bytes read, progress 58289/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 5792 Bytes read, progress 64081/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 1448 Bytes read, progress 65529/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 7 Bytes read, progress 65536/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 21713 Bytes read, progress 21713/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 1448 Bytes read, progress 23161/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 5792 Bytes read, progress 28953/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 4344 Bytes read, progress 33297/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 1448 Bytes read, progress 34745/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 5792 Bytes read, progress 40537/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 1448 Bytes read, progress 41985/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 5792 Bytes read, progress 47777/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 5792 Bytes read, progress 53569/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 1448 Bytes read, progress 55017/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 2896 Bytes read, progress 57913/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 4344 Bytes read, progress 62257/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 1448 Bytes read, progress 63705/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 1831 Bytes read, progress 65536/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 31473 Bytes read, progress 31473/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 1448 Bytes read, progress 32921/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 23168 Bytes read, progress 56089/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 1448 Bytes read, progress 57537/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 4344 Bytes read, progress 61881/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 2896 Bytes read, progress 64777/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 759 Bytes read, progress 65536/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 36889 Bytes read, progress 36889/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 1448 Bytes read, progress 38337/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 4344 Bytes read, progress 42681/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 10136 Bytes read, progress 52817/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 12719 Bytes read, progress 65536/65536 
I/HTTPStream( 65): 3209 Bytes read, progress 3209/65536 
E/HTTPStream( 65): recv failed, server is gone, total received: 3209 bytes
```

Again, works fine in 1.6 and 2.1 and the 2.2 *emulator*, just fails on a 2.2 *device*, specifically my HTC EVO 4G. Note this is using Wi-Fi with an excellent signal.

Comment: hmm I have a similar problem with 2.2 devices however my logs look completely different.  The streams actually work perfect for WiFi but die within 10 minutes on 3g on my 2.2 devices.   How about you?

Comment: Haven't tried 3G, using wi-fi when this happens.

Comment: Anyone? Can't figure this one out. You'd think if Google's own "playing a file or stream" tutorial doesn't work on 2.2 they would acknowledge it or change it, but no such luck.