# Why does it take so long for Android's MediaPlayer to prepare some live streams for playback?

Tags: android, audio, streaming, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I am finding big differences in the time it takes the Android MediaPlayer to prepare for live stream playback with different streams.

**The hard data**

I added logging between prepareAsync() and the onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) callback and tested several streams a few times each.  The times for each stream were very consistent (+/- one second), and here are the results:

1. MPR news stream: 27 seconds (http://newsstream1.publicradio.org:80/)
2. MPR classical music stream: 15 seconds (http://classicalstream1.publicradio.org:80/)
3. MPR The Current stream: 7 seconds (http://currentstream1.publicradio.org:80/)
4. PRI stream: 52 seconds (http://pri-ice.streamguys.biz/pri1)

The tests were performed on a Nexus S with Android 2.3.4 on a 3G connection (~1100 Kbps).

Playing non-streaming MP3 audio files is not an issue.

Here are snippets of how I am playing the streams:

Prepare MediaPlayer:

```
...
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(playUrl);
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
...
```

Then in onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp):

```
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Why does it take so long to prepare some streams but not others?  The above data seems to suggest that it *might* be based on the *amount* of data that has been buffered and not the *duration* of the buffered audio content.  Could this really be?

**Update:** I have tested live streaming on physical devices with Android 1.6, 2.2 and 2.3.4 and emulators with 1.6, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3.1 and 2.3.3.  I am only seeing the long delay on 2.3.3 and 2.3.4.  The older versions start playback within 5 seconds.

Comment: Were you able to come up with anything else on this?  I'm hitting the same and it is pretty frustrating.

Comment: No.  We decided to just live with it.

Comment: Very frustrated here as well.  My code worked great until I ran it on gingerbread.  Now it takes 1:50 to start streaming audio when it used to take 4-5 secs...

Comment: I faced the same issue concerning the long delay with devices > 2.3.3 (for mp3 streaming). It seems somehow related to the underlying media framework (OpenCore until 2.2 and StageFright after). Does anyone have any further information on how to handle it ?

Comment: I have the same issue and it seems to me that we should look for another player

Comment: Did anyone figure out an answer to this problem? I am also experiencing it

Comment: On Android 4+ it takes 15 to 20s to start hearing an IceCast stream, while on iOS 9 it takes at most 5s.

Answer (score 26):

It does appear that it is buffering a fixed amount of data rather than a fixed amount of time.  For anyone who doesn't know the bitrates of various types of NPR streams off the top of their head, the data looks like:

1. MPR news stream: 27 seconds (http://newsstream1.publicradio.org:80/), **64 kbps**
2. MPR classical music stream: 15 seconds (http://classicalstream1.publicradio.org:80/), **128 kbps**
3. MPR The Current stream: 7 seconds (http://currentstream1.publicradio.org:80/), **128 kbps**
4. PRI stream: 52 seconds (http://pri-ice.streamguys.biz/pri1), **32 kbps**

Apart from the discrepancy between the two 128 kbps streams, there is a very good correlation between bitrate and buffering duration.

In any case, Android is open-source, so you could always [look at what it's doing](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java).  Unfortunately, `prepareAsync()` and `prepare()` are native methods, and it appears that buffer-related events are dispatched from a native process as well.

Have you tried attaching an `OnBufferingUpdateListener` to the MediaPlayer to get finer-grained updates about the buffer-state?  It might be interesting to compare the rate at which the events are delivered and by what percentage the buffer fills on each event across the different streams.  You can cross-reference that against the stream bitrates, and if 4 seconds of buffering at 32 kbps fills the buffer the same percentage as 1 second of buffering at 128 kbps then I think you will have found your answer.

Comment: Thanks, aroth.  I did look at the source for `prepareAsync()` but saw that it was a native method.  The `onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int progress)` callback isn't fired before the player has been prepared.

Comment: How did you determine the bitrates of the streams?

Comment: @Jeremy - To determine the bitrate of the streams I used [VLC](http://videolan.org).  I just started playing each stream, and then checked the "Codec Info" display for each one.

Comment: I'm experiencing something similar but totally different - on a Samsung S3, none of the above streams play; at all. This is the only stream that I can get to play from everything I've tested so far: http://usa8-vn.mixstream.net:8138 My question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672568/mediaplayer-error-1-1004-aka-media-error-io-trying-to-stream-music-on-samsun

Answer (score 9):

Switch `MediaPlayer` by [FFmpegMediaPlayer](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer)
 works much betther than the `MediaPlayer` if you want to test your streams you can do it through the [demo](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer/blob/master/fmp-demo/FMPDemo.apk) that they have.

Comment: This worked for me. FFmpeg player plays the audio mp4 files much faster that any other player including native Android Media player and ExoPlayer. Thankyou for the pointer, it was in right direction :)

Comment: I have tried FFmpegMediaPlayer, but it increses my APK size from 6MB to 30MB. I think ExoPlayer is the best solution yet.

Comment: @EneasGesing Wow, It has been a while since I used FFmpeg player in any project, but I don't remember that It took so much space. Did you check the proguard configuration? Also did you add it as a gradle dependency, module dependency or as a jar?

Comment: For everyone reading this answer, THIS IS THE WAY TO GO! You probably already implemented the MediaPlayer class and all the related code, so to avoid rewriting too much code, you can almost seamlessly swap MediaPlayer to FFmpegMediaPlayer.

Comment: @4gus71n seems the `demo` link is no more available.

Answer (score 5):

I have recently debugged this same issue with a streaming audio provider. The issue is related to stagefright and streaming sources 32kbps and lower. We stepped through the same streaming measuring the response time at 24, 32, 48, 64 and 128 kbps.

- 24 -> 46 seconds to start streaming
- 32 -> 24 seconds to start streaming
- 48 -> 2 seconds to start streaming
- 64 -> 2 seconds to start streaming
- 128 -> 2 seconds to start streaming

This is from a consistent, wireless connection averaged over 10 attempts at each bit rate. The key, as Travis pointed out, was that stagefright could not figure out how long to buffer the audio. Sometimes i would see a message 'error: 1,-21492389' or so, which seemed to crash the stagefright player silently. I tried to track this down and eventually came to the conclusion that the very slow streams (sub 24 kbps) seemed to cause a buffer overflow because they would buffer until the device ran out of space for the audio stream.

I wanted to add that `OnBufferingUpdateListener` did not fire at all for me during this entire test. I don't know what it is there for. I think the only way you can tell how loading is going is to proxy the loading, in a similar fashion to the NPR app mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried this with 10 datapoints, three fast, 7 slow.
It's consistent, that is a fast stream is fast and a slow one is always slow.

I think it's related to the server delivered 'content-length,' Android doesn't know how much to buffer if the content-length isn't properly specified.

Could be wrong, didn't go as far as wiresharking.

Comment: I think you are right, cause I stream mp3 audio files from the VK social network on 2.3.4 and the MediaPlayer starts streaming almost immediately

Comment: Have you perhaps had success with this on a Samsung S3 device?

Answer (score 2):

If you're streaming from Icecast, take a look at the `burst-size` setting:

> The burst size is the amount of data (in bytes) to burst to a client
>   at connection time. Like burst-on-connect, this is to quickly fill the
>   pre-buffer used by media players. The default is 64 kbytes which is a
>   typical size used by most clients so changing it is not usually
>   required. This setting applies to all mountpoints unless overridden in
>   the mount settings. Ensure that this value is smaller than queue-size,
>   if necessary increase queue-size to be larger than your desired
>   burst-size. Failure to do so might result in aborted listener client
>   connection attempts, due to initial burst leading to the connection
>   already exceeding the queue-size limit.

I increased the `burst-size` to 131072 on my server, and now my Android app based on `MediaPlayer` plays streams without much delay.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem I decided to test if stream is available before opening the player. If you make the user to wait for a long time and the music will start it ok (it's not, but let's say it is ok).
The worst case scenario is to make him wait for a long time and the music will never start!
So, we have 2 situations:

- The live streaming scenario, like a radio station.
- The recorded mp3 file which is available online.

At the **radio scenario** we could check if the port is accepting connections (open/close state). If it is open prepare the player for the music, else do not prepare it at all.

```
public static boolean isLiveStreamingAvailable() {
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(STREAMING_HOST, STREAMING_PORT);
        // Create your socket
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        boolean online = true;
        // Connect with 10 s timeout
        try {
            socket.connect(sockaddr, 10000);
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException stex) {
            // treating timeout errors separately from other io exceptions
            // may make sense
            return false;
        } catch (IOException iOException) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            // As the close() operation can also throw an IOException
            // it must caught here
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // feel free to do something moderately useful here, eg log the event
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
```

At the **mp3 file scenario** the things are a little bit different. You should check for the response code which follows after the http request.

```
public static boolean isRecordedStreamingAvailable() {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
            // note : you may also need
            //        HttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)
            HttpURLConnection con =
                    (HttpURLConnection) new URL(RECORDED_URL).openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```