# MediaPlayer takes to long on prepareAsync, how to minimize time

Tags: android, stream, video-streaming, media-player, prepare

My issue is that the app stays about 3-4 seconds in the prepareAsync:
This takes to long, so i need to change something, to minimize the time it stays there.

This is my code:

```
    if (path_to_play == "") {
                fragmentNavigator.setErrorMessage("notif test: Video url cannot be accessed");
            }
            setSurfaceHolder();
            updateStatistics();
            loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path_to_play);
            if ((holder != null) && (holder.getClass() != null) && holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            } else {
                LogService.log(TAG, "notif test: holder: " + holder);
                setSurfaceHolder();
            }
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            LogService.log(TAG, "notif test: IllegalArgumentException called");
            LogService.err(TAG, e.getMessage(), e, 1);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            LogService.log(TAG, "notif test: IllegalStateException called");
            LogService.err(TAG, e.getMessage(), e, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LogService.log(TAG, "notif test: IOException called");
            doCleanUp();
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            LogService.log(TAG, "notif test: NullPointerException called");
            LogService.err(TAG, e.getMessage(), e, 1);
        }
```

This is what my onPrepare function looks like:

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
    startVideoPlayback(); //function that starts the video
}
```

This is the StartVideoPlayback function:

```
private void startVideoPlayback() {
    LogService.log(TAG, "startVideoPlayback()");

    if (holder.getSurface() == null) {
        setSurfaceHolder();
    }
    if (record_canceled) {
        wasPaused = true;
        LogService.log(TAG, "waspaused intent: " + wasPaused);
    }
    if (/* VideoDataManager.getInstance().getVideoRecorded() || */wasPaused) {
        LogService.log(TAG, "seek");
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(100);
        play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    } else if (record_canceled) {
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
        }
        play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    } else {
        LogService.log(TAG, "dont seek: " + wasPaused);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(100);
        wasPaused = false;
        play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
    }
    updateButtonStates();
    updateStatistics();

    loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    if (VideoDataManager.getInstance().getVideoRecorded() && wasPaused) {
        LogService.log(TAG, "------- pause the new recorded video, setVideoRecorded(false)");
        // VideoDataManager.getInstance().setVideoRecorded(false);
    }

    if (VideoDataManager.getInstance().getVideoRecorded() && mReloadVideo) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        // if ((ni != null) && (ni.getState() ==
        // NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) {
        // fragmentNavigator.uploading();
        // }
        mReloadVideo = false;
    } else if ((VideoHolderActivity.notificationBar.getTextMessageTag(VideoHolderActivity.notificationTextMessage).equals("new") || VideoHolderActivity.notificationBar.getTextMessageTag(VideoHolderActivity.notificationTextMessage).equals("gcm")) && (all_videos.size() > 1)) {
        fragmentNavigator.BackButtonForNotification();
        VideoDataManager.getInstance().setVideoRecorded(false);
    } else if (runOfflineReload) {
        setVideoPlayback();
        runOfflineReload = false;
    }

}
```

Also tried the onBufferingUpdate Listener, instead of the onPrepared, using this code:

```
    @Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    LogService.log(TAG, "-------------------Onbuffering time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimePrepare) + "||||percentage: " + percent);
    if (isAsync) {
        LogService.log(TAG, "-------------------Onbuffering time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimePrepare));
        mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = true;
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown && pm.isScreenOn()) {
            startVideoPlayback();
            downloadService();
            mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(null);
            isAsync = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Sometimes, when the onBufferingUpdate is called twice, once at 100 and once about at 60-80%, i manage to save about 1000ms. But this is not enough. Can't i make it be called faster, somehow? at about 30%?

Comment: I don't have a real answer for this but this will help your app to be less frustrating for the user (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582908/why-does-it-take-so-long-for-androids-mediaplayer-to-prepare-some-live-streams/42042218#42042218)